# laravel chaining isForceDeleting() events (on observers)

Tags: php, laravel, relational-database

I'm using laravel observers to make sure, my related models are deleted all the time.

**Order:**

```
public function conversation()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Conversation');
}
```

**Conversation:**

```
public function involvedUsers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ConversationUser');
}

public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Message')->latest();
}
```

I'm trying to delete now all conversations, in case of an order is deleted "permanently".

**OrderObserver:**

```
public function deleting(Order $order)
{
    if ($order->isForceDeleting()) {
        $order->conversation()->forceDelete();
    }
}
```

**ConversationObserver:**

```
public function deleting(Conversation $conversation)
{
    if ($conversation->isForceDeleting()) {
        $conversation->messages()->forceDelete();
        $conversation->involvedUsers()->forceDelete();
    }
}
```

It seems like the `deleting` event of the `ConversationObserver` isn't fired at all.
Instead I get this exception:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`shop`.`conversation_users`, CONSTRAINT `conversation_users_conversation_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`conversation_id`) REFERENCES `conversations` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `conversations` where `conversations`.`order_id` = 18 and `conversations`.`order_id` is not null)

What is failing in my code above, using an observer (I want to avoid deleting all conversation related things inside the order observer itself). Any idea?

Comment: I recommend you rephrase the question to avoid getting negative votes related to "primarily opinion-based". What's "most elegant" can be a matter of opinion/debate, which is not desired on Stack Overfow (see the topics about asking in the [help] if you're unfamiliar with this).

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly related to how you are calling your delete on the original Conversation model.

When you call `$something->conversations()->delete()`, **you are only executing SQL**, so your deleting event will not be triggered. The way Laravel relations work, `$something->conversations()` simply pulls a Query Builder class, so you can use any of the Query Builder functions on it.

Think about it from the other perspective:  If you call `$something->conversations` (without parenthesis on the conversation field), this is very different. This pulls your conversation objects from the database and gives them to you in a **Collection**. That's why when you call `delete()` on each one, your delete events get triggered.

Take a look at your pulls for the conversation model, and how you are getting them prior to deleting.  If one way as above, try changing it to solve your issue.

There are quite a few feeds on this that may help detail the explanation.  Try one of the [original 'bug' reports and the conversation around it](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2536).

Comment: I know the difference between a collection and eloquent objects iteself, but using `$conversation->messages()->forceDelete();` is eloquent object based.

Comment: Yes, as is everything. It is the type of object that makes the difference in this case. But I'm confused - are you deleting messages via the above comment and then also looking to delete in the observer? If so, that's possibly your problem.  The Conversation observer won't fire on the deletion of messages in that chain.  If it did for some reason, then the messages would possibly already be gone and create a fail.  You've got a few potential issues here, which will hopefully make for an easy solve.

Answer (score 0):

when you call relation with `()` it returns you query builder instance not eloquent model collection and when you call it without `()` it will returns you collection and then by collections `map` you can call forceDelete Method on all one by one.

Eloquent events only works when you retrieve the models and then call methods.

like `User::where('id',1)->delete();` will not trigger `deleting` and `deleted` as you never get the model from database so no event binds its just equivalent to `\DB::table('users')->where('id',1)->delete();`

But when you call `User::where('id',1)->first()->delete();` Or `User::find(1)->delete();` now eloquent events of `deleting` and `deleted` will triggered as you create their models first by getting data from DB then whatever events binds to this Model are registered and when you call delete it will trigger its events.

On Order Observer you need to retrieve the model and then call forceDelete

```
public function deleting(Order $order)
{
    if ($order->isForceDeleting()) {
        $order->conversation->forceDelete();        //parenthesis removed
    }
}
```

Comment: `$order->conversation->forceDelete();` solved it. Since the relation to an conversation was of type `hasOne` no collection was returned (meaning `map` won't work).